# Unregister event handler in MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I register an event handler (delegate) in the `Start` method within a class inherited from `MonoBehaviour`. I want to prevent memory leaks in this case.

```
public class CharactersController: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        npc.CollisionEntered += OnNpcCollisionEnter;
    }
}
```

What is correct or the best method to unregister the delegate?
There is a method `OnDestroy` [http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html](http://OnDestroy)

The doc says that

> This function is called when the MonoBehaviour will be destroyed.
>
> OnDestroy will only be called on game objects that have previously
> been active.

But it's not clear when MonoBehaviour will be destroyed and what if a gameobject hasn't been activated previously.

Comment: It sounds clear to me that `OnDestroy` is *not* called if the game object hasn't been active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Start()` method will not get called unless the behavior is enabled](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html). And it can only be enabled if the game object that it's on is activated. So, you can safely assume that if the behavior gets `OnDestroy()` called, it did get a call to `Start()` earlier.

[The destruction of mono behaviour happens within the same frame (before rendering)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html). However, if you are not just asking this because of precaution for memory leaks, but your logic depends on that, something is definitely wrong with it.

As @Programmer correctly noted, your code, most likely, should subscribe and unsubscribe to events in `OnEnabled` and `OnDisabled` instead. This follows the concept of [component design pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) much better: after all, this pattern assumes (and quite logically so) that components only do their work when deliberately activated by outside systems, and go back to sleep when deactivated. Now, Unity developers have to bend these guidelines a little in a lot of places, because MonoBehaviours are almost the only point of entry they have in terms of C# code, but still, it's better to follow the implicit rules of the system.

And finally, I honestly never saw considerable performance problems in a Unity project because of memory leaks. It is a good that you thinking about it, but your time would be considerably better spent if you eliminated instantiation and destruction of the objects altogether, by moving them to use an [object pool](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling), as they are much more often tend to be a source of problems.

Comment: @Programmer in my case Destroy + OnDestroy works as I expected. I know where I instantiate object from prefab, and know where I destroy the object.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment; are you replying to @Programmer or to me? In case you are replying to me: your statement of fact implies that this fact is opposed to what I wrote, but it's not. This is exactly what I wrote too.

Comment: Well then I don't understand — are you just agreeing with me? Or did that statement contradict something in my answer?

Comment: I totally agree with you. What I need, to get full control of gameobject and its lifetime. Now, as I said, I know where I register my delegate (Start method), and unregister it (OnDestroy method). Using OnEnable with OnDisable also can improve my workflow. In this case I shouldn't call Destroy method. Also found article with gameobject lifetime and what methods can be used http://www.madpixelmachine.com/2013/07/05/monobehaviour-lifecycle-and-leaks-explained/

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding. It's just when people reply with a simple of fact I perceive it to be a counter-argument.

Answer (score 4):

It is appropriate to register events in **OnEnable** and unregister them in **OnDisable**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only registering the one handler on `Start` and your `CharactersController` lasts the lifetime of the application then you aren't going to be leaking memory. It would be more likely to leak if you were registering the handler at some recurring event in the object's lifetime, and then not unregistering it later.